# Imported Component not being rendered in the HTML DOM

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I am using `React Testing Library` to test the frontend of my application.

I have a component cause `OrgList`, which renders a list of cards on the screen. Also it imports another component `PaginationList` which is used to display a pagination bar at the bottom on the page.

The issue that I am facing with the same is that when I'm calling the `render` method on the `OrgList` component in a test, all the card components are being rendered (and their HTML is generated in `screen.debug()` method, but the `Pagination` component is not being rendered.

The concerned files (truncated to only contain the relevant portions) are:

### OrgList.tsx

```
import SuperDashListCard from 'components/SuperDashListCard/SuperDashListCard';
import PaginationList from 'components/PaginationList/PaginationList';

...

function OrgList(): JSX.Element {

  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(5);
  
  ... 

  return (
    <>
    ...
           <div className={styles.list_box}>
              {data &&
                (rowsPerPage > 0
                  ? data.organizationsConnection.slice(
                      page * rowsPerPage,
                      page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage
                    )
                  : data.organizationsConnection
                ).map(
                  (datas: {
                    _id: string;
                    image: string;
                    name: string;
                    admins: any;
                    members: any;
                    createdAt: string;
                    location: string | null;
                  }) => {
                    return (
                      <SuperDashListCard
                        id={datas._id}
                        key={datas._id}
                        image={datas.image}
                        admins={datas.admins}
                        members={datas.members.length}
                        createdDate={dayjs(parseInt(datas?.createdAt)).format(
                          'DD/MM/YYYY'
                        )}
                        orgName={datas.name}
                        orgLocation={datas.location}
                      />
                    );
                  }
                )}
            </div>
            <div>
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <PaginationList
                      data-testid="pagination"
                      count={data ? data.organizationsConnection.length : 0}
                      rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
                      page={page}
                      onPageChange={handleChangePage}
                      onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
                    />
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
    ...
    </>
  );
}

export default OrgList;
```

### OrgList.test.ts

```
...

import OrgList from './OrgList';

...

describe('OrgList Pagination Testing', () => {
  test('Default Case: Only first five organization details should be shown in the correct order', async () => {
    const { container } = render(
      <MockedProvider addTypename={false} mocks={MOCKS}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Provider store={store}>
            <I18nextProvider i18n={i18nForTest}>
              <OrgList />
            </I18nextProvider>
          </Provider>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </MockedProvider>
    );
    await wait();

    expect(container.textContent).toMatch(organizationsConnection[0].name);
    expect(container.textContent).toMatch(organizationsConnection[4].name);
    expect(container.textContent).not.toMatch(organizationsConnection[5].name);
      
    screen.debug(undefined, Infinity);
    // The rendered HTML has no pagination component

    ...
  });
});
```

Due to the non-availability of this component, I am unable to test its functionality properly with the `OrgList` component. Can anyone help me resolving this?

#### Update

You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/EshaanAgg/talawa-admin/tree/page_test/)
The files that might be of interest to you are [OrgList.tsx](https://github.com/EshaanAgg/talawa-admin/tree/page_test/src/screens/OrgList), [OrgListPagination.Test.tsx](https://github.com/EshaanAgg/talawa-admin/blob/page_test/src/screens/OrgList/OrgListPagination.test.tsx) and [PaginationList.tsx](https://github.com/EshaanAgg/talawa-admin/blob/page_test/src/components/PaginationList/PaginationList.tsx).

Comment: Can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example? We need to see the `PaginationList` code

Comment: @LinDu I wasn't able to create "isolate" the bug due to the huge nature of the repository, but I have added the links for the same in the question, along with the links to the required files.